# How to explicitly call const version of the member function?

Tags: c++, overloading

I have an overloaded member function in single class. The differences between two return type and const modifier:

```
class A
{
public:
    int mass() const {return m_mass;}
protected:
    int& mass() {return m_mass;}
private:
    int m_mass;
};
```

But by default having non-const instance of class `A` will cause non-const version of overloaded function to be called:

```
int main() 
{
    A a;
    return (const int)a.mass();
}
```

> error: `int& A::mass()` is protected within this context

How can the `const` version be called explicitly in this case?

Comment: `((const A &)a).mass()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++17 will introduce [`std::as_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const), which is a really simple utility that you can implement yourself until then:

```
A a;
std::as_const(a).mass();
```

Answer (score 7):

You simply use a named `const` reference to it, or better still, use `const_cast` to obtain an unnamed `const` reference to it, then call.

```
int main() 
{
    A a;

    //1
    const A& a_const = a;
    a_const.mass();                

    //2
    const_cast<const A&>(a).mass(); 

    //3
    //in C++17
    //std::as_const(a).mass();          //3
}
```

---

With C++17 and later you can use [`std::as_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const).

Comment: @Barry, Fixed. Thanks. Though, the former code was still correct. (because `static_cast` can also introduce `cv` qualifiers), additional unintended conversions can happen with `static_cast`. I once got nuked by that such. :-)

Comment: Yeah, it was correct, but `const_cast` defends against all those other things you just mentioned. Plus, it's just more explicit. We're const casting.